# What is a bounded sequence of holomorphic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C^n$ open, $\{f_n\}_n\subseteq\operatorname{hol}(\Omega,\Bbb C)$ bounded.

What does this mean?

A numerical sequence $(a_n)_n\subset\Bbb C$ is bounded if $\exists M>0$ s.t. $|a_n|\le M\;\;\forall n\in\Bbb N$.

So I thought that a sequence of functions is bounded if it is so in norm; $\operatorname{hol}(\Omega,\Bbb C)$ could be endowed with the norm of the uniform convergence on compact subsets, so I'd say that a sequence like the one at the beginning is bounded if
$$
\forall K\Subset\Omega\;\;\exists M_K>0\;:\;||f_n||_{\infty,K}:=\max_{z\in K}|f_n(z)|\le M_K\;\;\forall n.
$$

Is this right?

Comment: What does $\Subset$ mean? I would interpret the statement as there exists some $K$ such that $\sup_{z \in \Omega} |f_n(z)| \le K$ for all $n$.

Comment: $K\Subset\Omega$ means that $K$ is compact in $\Bbb C^n$ and it is contained in $\Omega$.

Comment: Yes! What you wrote was my first idea... but it sounds like $(f_n)_n$ is *uniformly* bounded. My definition is less restrictive.

Comment: I'd much rather say "a sequence of bounded holomorphic functions."